# How are anti-unitary transformations symmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, unitarity

In the article on [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem), unitary transformations ($U$) can be clearly seen as symmetric from: 
$T: \Psi =\{e^{ia} \Psi|a \in R \} \mapsto \Psi^{'} =\{e^{ib}U \Psi|b \in R \} $

and hence, 
the inner product property is preserved: 
$(T\Psi,T\Phi)=(\Psi,\Phi)$

But with the anti-unitary operator $A$,

$T: \Psi =\{e^{ia} \Psi|a \in R \} \mapsto \Psi^{'} =\{e^{ib}A \Psi|b \in R \} $

Since $A\Psi=\Psi^*$

Transformation $T$ associated with $A$ renders the inner product as:
$(T\Psi,T\Phi)=(\Phi,\Psi)$

Clearly the inner product property is not preserved as the inner product is flipped, not same. What exactly is symmetric about anti-unitary transformations?

Comment: In that article, a symmetry transformation is defined in terms of preserving a ray product which takes the complex *magnitude* of the inner product. I think the basic idea is to preserve *probability* rather than *probability amplitude*.

Answer (score 2):

Time reversal must be unitary or antiunitary. But the standard definition further demands that it is antiunitary in particular. An antiunitary operator is a bijection $T : H \mapsto H$ that satisfies,

1. (*adjoint inverse*)$\quad \, T^{*}T = T T^{*} = I$, and
2. (*antilinearity*) $ \quad \,T(a\psi + b\phi) = a^{*}T \psi + b^{*}T \phi$.

It is sometimes useful to note that these conditions are together equivalent to,

3. $\langle T \psi, T \phi \rangle = \langle \psi, \phi \rangle^{∗}$

Properties $(2)$ and $(3)$ underlie claims that time reversal ‘involves conjugation’. Theyare also slippery properties that often throw beginners (and many experts) for a
loop, since they require many of the familiar properties of linear operators to be
subtly adjusted.